# How to perform batch methods renaming in Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea

I have a set of Java projects that use the same library. The problem is that the previous version of the library included classes which methods names started from upper-case characters like MyClass.DoSomething(). The next version of the library became more "Java-friendly" and method names were changed to lowerCamelCase like MyClass.doSomething().

Now I need to rename all these methods in all of my projects, but doing it manually is a long and boring task.

I wonder is there exists some IDE plugin or tool that may perform this task automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Most (Any?) modern IDEs have method rename refactoring feature. In Intellij Idea it is <kbd>Shift-F6</kbd> when your cursor is at the method name. So one of the options is to rename each of the methods.

You could also write a hacky script which I think should work for most of the cases and all other cases could be done manually. It would search for entries like `.DoSomething(` and replace them with `.doSomething(`.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE? Netbeans allows you to do project-wide search and replace, so you just need to do that once for each function.

Alternatively you can open up the old version of the library project (if it is open source) and change your library dependency to be a project one. Now go through and refactor the library project to the new names and it will rename all the old references in your code at the same time. Once you are done ditch your copy of the project and switch back to the library but the changes from refactoring will remain.

Comment: I can use any IDE that will perform the task. The library is not open source.

Comment: Another option will just be to open the project in net beans, then go through the list of errors. Ctrl space on each error should fix the problem by auto complete to the correct name.